# Jax-WS unknown namespace definition in soap call

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I've designed a new WebService with JAX-WS and Spring under the hood.

I don't like arrays, so I choosed java collections & lists in the method signatures.

Using I got an unusable WebMethod (in the following example unlockBusComponent) because  in the generated wsdl is a namespace "misconfigured".

First the entities:

```java
@XmlRootElement(namespace ="appstate.entities.web.company.tld",
name="ApplicationState") 
  public class ApplicationState {
        private UUID applicationId;
        private String applicationName;
        private String hostName;
        private String status;
        public ApplicationState() {}//... public getter & setter are following

}
@XmlRootElement(namespace ="buscomponent.entities.web.company.tld") 
  public class BusComponent {
        private UUID lockId;
        private int mandantId;
        private String name;
        //... public getter & setter are following

}
```

Now The Service:

```java
@WebService
public interface BusComponentInfoService {

    @WebMethod
    public Collection<BusComponent> getBusComponent(/** */
    @WebParam(name = "mandantId") final int mandantId,/** */
    @WebParam(name = "application") final ApplicationState application) throws Throwable;

    @WebMethod
    public void unlockBusComponent(/** */
    @WebParam(name = "busComponent")
    final BusComponent busComponent) throws Throwable;
}

@Component
@WebService(endpointInterface = "tld.company.BusComponentInfoService")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public class BusComponentInfoServiceImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements BusComponentInfoService {

    @Override
    public Collection<BusComponent> getBusComponent(final int mandantId, final ApplicationState application) throws Throwable {
        //....
        final Collection<BusComponent> retval = new ArrayList<BusComponent>();
        return retval;
    }

    @Override
    public void unlockBusComponent(final BusComponent busComponent) throws Throwable {
        //....
    }

}
```

To test the service I use SoapUI, that works very well!
Here the request:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:bci="http://bci.lockserver.company.tld/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bci:getBusComponent>
         <mandantId>1</mandantId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <application>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <applicationId>12345678-abcd-0987-edcb-1234567890ab</applicationId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <applicationName>SoapUI Dummy</applicationName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hostName>mycomputer</hostName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <status>?</status>
         </application>
      </bci:getBusComponent>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And the response:

```xml
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns3:getBusComponentResponse xmlns:ns2="buscomponent.entities.web.company.tld" xmlns:ns3="http://bci.lockserver.common.company.tld/" xmlns:ns4="appstate.entities.web.company.tld">
         <return>
            <lockId>b6226670-b7c6-43e7-bd65-5f73789ae90f</lockId>
            <mandantId>1</mandantId>
            <name>ABCDEF_001</name>
         </return>
      </ns3:getBusComponentResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

This request above works fine. But the following request unlockBusComponent was generated by SoapUI with a namespace for the submitted buscompontents.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:bci="http://bci.lockserver.common.company.tld/" 
xmlns:bus="buscomponent.entities.web.company.tld">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bci:unlockBusComponent>
         <bus:busComponent>
            <lockId>b6226670-b7c6-43e7-bd65-5f73789ae90f</lockId>
            <mandantId>1</mandantId>
            <name>ABCDEF_001</name>
         </bus:busComponent>
      </bci:unlockBusComponent>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The given BusComponent Entity will not transfered to the service. The expected parameter is null on server-side. If I remove the **bus**-namespace from the **bus:busComponent**-Tags, the buscomponent will be successfully transfered to the service.

So my questions are:

1. Whats wrong with the buscomponent-entity? (Please notice the WebMethod "getBusComponent" with parameter ApplicationState works very well!)
2. After a redesign (switching from single values and collections to arrays of buscomponent-entities), the new services are working very well. But why? Whats different to the approach before?

Now the successfull working service:

```java
@WebService
public interface BusComponentInfoService {

    @WebMethod
    public BusComponent[] getBusComponent(/** */
    @WebParam(name = "mandantId")   final int mandantId, /**     */
    @WebParam(name = "application") final ApplicationState application) throws Throwable;

    @WebMethod
    public void unlockBusComponents(/** */
    @WebParam(name = "busComponent")    final BusComponent[] busComponent) throws Throwable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections are language specific implementation. For collections there are no equivalent XML data types available.

Current Limitations of JAXB
The java.util.Collection classes cannot be used with rpc/literal or document/literal BARE style due to a limitation in JAXB. However, they do work in the default document/literal WRAPPED style.

[LINK](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2/docs/ReleaseNotes.html)

use arrays to communicate then convert it to your collection.

Comment: I agree with you, that collections are a bad in my case. But: The WebMethod, which won't work doesn't handle a collection or an array. Just switching to an array implementation "solved" it. And the second thing is, that im using @SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)